# Getting the mean of 2 variables across a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, lapply

After my `replicate()` call below, I was wondering how I could get the `mean` of `'Estimate'` and `'Std. Error'` for `x1` and `x2` across the list?

```
foo <- function(){
x1 <- rnorm(20) ; x2 <- rnorm(20,2); y <- rnorm(20,3)
coef(summary(lm(y~x1+x2)))[,1:2]  }

# Now replicate foo():

replicate(2, foo(), simplify = F) # How to get the mean of 'Estimate' and 'Std. Error' for 'x1' and 'x2' after loop

 ### OUTPUT:

[[1]]
              Estimate  Std. Error
(Intercept)  3.1356507  0.4874282
x1          -0.3408958  0.2033072
x2          -0.1335315  0.2513356

[[2]]
             Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept) 2.5574090  0.4354596
x1          0.0850336  0.3101341
x2          0.2348902  0.1754149
```

Comment: If you store that list in a variable like `x`, you could do `do.call('+', x) / length(x)`. That will take the mean of all elements in the matrix. Will your list always have 2 items?

Comment: @MrFlick, it could have more, also I'm open to using any packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we fix the list so that we can see the results for different methods:

```
set.seed(111)
dat = replicate(2, foo(), simplify = F)

dat
[[1]]
               Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  3.47644151  0.4100162
x1          -0.04314488  0.2769444
x2          -0.04946731  0.1860911

[[2]]
               Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  2.96378594  0.5265807
x1           0.22268874  0.3517643
x2          -0.04437585  0.2468499
```

Using base R "Reduce" :

```
Reduce(`+`,dat)/length(dat)
               Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  3.22011373  0.4682984
x1           0.08977193  0.3143544
x2          -0.04692158  0.2164705
```

Using purrr:

```
library(purrr)
reduce(dat,`+`)/length(dat)

               Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  3.22011373  0.4682984
x1           0.08977193  0.3143544
x2          -0.04692158  0.2164705
```

Comment: they are not equivalent... if you have a list of 3, you will see that ```do.call``` will throw an error. Imagine you have a function ```f(x,y)```  and you want to apply onto ```a,b and c```. ```Reduce(f,list(a,b,c))```  will do ```f ( f(a,b), c)```

Comment: ```do.call``` will only work on functions that take one or more input, so using ```do.call(f,list(a,b,c))``` will do ```f(a,b,c...)``` and you can see why "+" doesn't work, because it works on 2 variables

Comment: @rnorouzian, it's a very good question.. Hope i errrmm do not sound too abstract =_='

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution could be

```
library(tidyverse)
replicate(2, foo(), simplify = FALSE) %>% #could use purrr::rerun here
  map_df(as_tibble, rownames = "coef") %>% 
  group_by(coef) %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = mean))

  coef        Estimate `Std. Error`
  <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>
1 (Intercept)    3.58         0.514
2 x1            -0.131        0.206
3 x2            -0.223        0.224
```

Comment: First line could be `rerun(.n = 2, foo())` no great advantage here but .id argument can be very useful. You need dplyr v 1.0.0 for across. Replaces `summarise_at` etc

Comment: `dplyr 1.0.0` has not been updated within `tidyverse`. when I updated `dplyr` individually it gave a hell lot of problems. So, `across` is essentially absent in the `tidyverse` at this time.

Comment: you can just use a regular summarise - something like `summarise(e = mean(Estimate), s = mean(`Std. Error`)`

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can also convert to `array` and get the `mean`.  It would also take care of `NA` elements if present

```
apply(array(unlist(dat), c(3, 2, 2)), 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,]  3.22011373 0.4682984
#[2,]  0.08977193 0.3143544
#[3,] -0.04692158 0.2164705
```

#### data

```
set.seed(111)
dat <- replicate(2, foo(), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, Arun, little by little I want to learn `tidyverese`. It uses a more consistabnt grammar.

Comment: @rnorouzian I thought you only wanted a base R solution (as always)

Comment: You're right but I have started exploring `tidyverse`!